# Class methods returning NULL Variables

Tags: php

I have a Class that is setting up an API to parse the DOM of an external website in order to populate somebody's profile with character data from a game. My problem is that every single variable associated with any class on this page is returning null. Why? Here is the code(s) that are relevant. I am not getting the ID in this manner, but I extracted the code to a temporary page to simplify the debugging.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

require_once '../bootstrap.php';
$api = new GetCharacter($id,$db);
$data = $api->output();
```

Bootstrap is just your usual run of the mill database connection and definition setup. Everything in there works okay and all variables are returning their correct results (ie, the $db variable has a valid connection - tested inline too.) If I echo or var_dump the results of every variable from bootstrap.php they are all correct.

Here is GetCharacter (I have removed all the methods because my problem doesn't involve them):

```
class GetCharacter {

    private $api, $db, $html;
    public $data, $id;

    public function __constructor($id, $db) {

        $this->id = $id;
        $this->api = new GetAPI;
        $this->db = $db;

    }
}
```

Now if I make a dummy function to return, var_dump, print_r $db, it's NULL. Same for $api and $id. What's going on? I feel like I must be missing something exceptionally obvious. I'm passing $id and $db into the class on construction via dependency injection and I've never not had it work in this manner. It's simply **not working** and I have no idea why.

I have tried numerous things:

- Changed the $db to $this->db = new Database; instead, to see if there was a scoping issue with the injection. Still NULL.
- Made the $this->id defined inside the constructor and not via injection. It still returns NULL. Let me make it really clear what happened there. **In the constructor I put $this->id = '123456' and the returned value was NULL.** - WTF?
- Used global $id (I don't WANT to, but desperate times...) and still NULL.

I then made a dummy function:

```
public function WTF() {

    return 'WHAT THE HELL IS GOING ON';
}
```

When I call this in the page with echo $api->WTF() nothing happens. For all intents and purposes, it seems like my Class is undefined but it's not, because otherwise it wouldn't even return NULL on var_dump. I'm also getting zero errors with error_reporting(-1) set.

After nearly two hours of trying to debug this I'm utterly stumped.

Comment: why you passing just one parameter in $api = new GetCharacter($id); instead of two i.e., $api = new GetCharacter($id,$db);

Comment: That's just a cut/paste issue, I'll change it. It's the after math of my attempted fix in the first of my list. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: `__constructor`? isn't it `__construct`

Comment: Like I said. I'm missing something obvious. Holy crap. I officially retire from web programming when I first wake up. You should post this as an answer so I can accept it and give you the kudos you deserve.

Comment: Incidentally, NetBeans is not rejecting 'constructor' as invalid which is (probably, I'd like to think so) why I missed that, I think (obviously because it thinks I want to name a class constructor). Thanks again, I feel pretty stupid right now but just glad I can stop ripping my hair out! :-)

Comment: @WoodyPayne that's odd with netbeans not tellin' that. i not using netbeans right now so i can't tell why it doesn't highlight it.

Comment: Indeed, I guess it's just assuming that I both don't want a construct method and that I _do_ want a constructor method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its supposed to be `__construct()` for the constructor:

```
public function __construct($id, $db) { // not constructor

    $this->id = $id;
    $this->api = new GetAPI;
    $this->db = $db;

}
```

Then when you instantiate.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

require_once '../bootstrap.php';
$api = new GetCharacter($id,$db);
echo $api->WTF(); // WHAT THE HELL IS GOING ON
```

Sidenote: You should also turn on error reporting so that you'll know whats up.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```